# Determine even position in a list and take out second occurence

Tags: prolog

I just learned prolog for a week and I have to write a prolog program that counts the number of times an element appearing in a list L at even positions.

I have try to figure out the problem for the from am 12:00 to now (am 4:00 last 16 hours) and fail.

1.What I have tried until now is like

```
count(_,[],0).
count(E,[E|L],C):-!,count(E,L,C1),C is C1+1.
count(E,[A|L],C):-atom(A),count(E,L,C),!.
count(E,[A|L],C):-count(E,A,C1),count(E,L,C2),C is C1+C2.
```

It just can count the occurence of the whole list within the element is a list.

2.The second is takeoutsecond occurence element in list

What I have tried until now is like but fail

```
takeout(A,[A|B],B). 
takeout(A,[B|C],[B|D]) :- takeout(A,C,D). 
takeoutSecond(A,[B|C],[B|D]):- takeoutSecond(A,C,D). 
takeoutSecond(A,[A|B],[A|C]):- takeout(A,B,C).
```

3.Can you give me some hint if takeoutsecondlast without reverse? I will appreciate it!

Can you give me some hint, I do my all effort on it.

I will reply not now because I stay up late, and I apology for it.
Thank for reading my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you miss a very simple use of Prolog pattern matching: namely, to match the second element just ignore the first

```
match_second(E, [_,E|Rest], Rest).
```

You can use that as 'building block' for your assignment, but it's so simple that really you'll be better to integrate it in your efforts. Use that pattern in the *head* of your predicates.